# Prevent WooCommerce brand from being sellable

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Hi there we have an online store running on `WooCommerce` and using the WooCommerce brands plugin (http://docs.woothemes.com/document/wc-brands/) but there is one brand that we are allowed show online with price but not allowed to actually sell.

Is there a function I can add for this particular brand to `functions.php` that will change the add to cart button in category or widget layout to "more info" and link to the product and then on the product page instead of the add to cart section just have a text message saying to call the store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter WooCommerce's `is_purchasable` method. Any item that returns `false` will not be able to be purchased.

```
function so_26378581_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ){
    if ( has_term( 'your-brand', 'product_brand', $product->id  ) ){
        $purchasable = false;
    }
    return $purchasable;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'so_26378581_purchasable', 10, 2 );
```

This uses conditional logic to test whether the `$product` in question has the `your-brand` term in the `product_brand` taxonomy... via the [`has_term()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) function.

By the way, this is not the type of functionality that belongs in `functions.php`. Your theme should only be concerned with display/appearances. I would recommend that you make this its own plugin, or add to to a [site specific snippets](http://ottopress.com/2011/creating-a-site-specific-snippets-plugin/) plugin.

Comment: Thank you Helga, this worked I just had to change 'brands' to 'product_brand'.

Comment: Great. I've adjusted the code to reflect the correct taxonomy.

Comment: Hi Helga I'm wondering can you help me again quickly we're getting this error when someone adds something to their cart;

Comment: Warning: Missing argument 2 for so_26378581_purchasable() in /home/sitename/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme/functions.php on line 425

Comment: Looks like I forgot to declare the second parameter in the `add_action` statement. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

to me it made no error message, but it did not work, as applied in my test subject and stand continues with two products of different brands.

I put this code:

```
function so_26378581_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ){
if ( has_term( 'product_brand', 'product_brand', $product->id  ) ){
    $purchasable = false;
}
return $purchasable;
```

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'so_26378581_purchasable', 10, 2 );